# how to intercept a click on a <button> tag and stop the submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, confirm

I have a form with some button tags, one of which is a delete button. I want to intercept the click and ask confirmation.
I can intercept it with the code below, but it processes anyway no matter what I answer.

HTML:

```
<button type=submit id=mydelbuttonid value=delete name=deletebutton>Delete</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button#mydelbuttonid').on("click", function(e) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) {
    alert('deleting');
  }
  else {
    alert('not deleting');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

I get the correct alert, but the record is deleted anyway.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I've searched the internet for quite a while and find a lot of solutions for `<a>` tags, but none for `<button>` tags.

Comment: Just as a side note, `event` != `e`

Comment: @A.Wolff That's the main note. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ya on FF it would... :)

Comment: Try binding to the form's submit instead of the button's click

Answer (score 3):

As @A.Wolff correctly points out, `e !== event`...

Changing `event` to `e` or vice-versa will allow `preventDefault` to actually get triggered (after which the `return false` becomes redundant).

```
$('button#mydelbuttonid').on("click", function(e) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) {
    alert('deleting');
  }
  else {
    alert('not deleting');
    e.preventDefault();
    /*return false;*/
  }
})
```

Comment: Ya but that would be an issue only on FF which doesn't use global event model and so throwing an error. On other browser, it would work as expected. I think it should be noted :)  BTW, the `return false;` statement is then redundant there